# What is the best practice to represent hierarchical data in navigation?

Tags: android, navigation

For example I have class **Category**:

```
class Category {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Category> childCategories;
}
```

And I want to show List of this objects and user could go down through child categories and back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a built-in [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) which is two-level. You can show your categories and your child categories in there. When user clicks on a child category you can launch another activity, displaying the child category contents.

Maybe you will not want to use ExpandableListView but only list views, so you display a single level in a single screen.

Android does not have ExpandableListView fragment so probably the right way to go is to display each category in a separate screen. Probably  you could use the same Activity for all your categories though.

Android definitely does not have any TreeView-like controls. That's probably because device screens can be quite small. Displaying one level at a time would probably be fine.

Comment: And do you know how items are represented in file explorers? I think there are no separated screens.

Comment: @pepela Why, I see right now on my Samsung the pre-installed 'My Files' application, a single screen per directory